# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

```
<script>
function urlencode(str) {
   return escape(str).replace('+', '%2B').replace('%20', '+').replace('*', '%2A').replace('/', '%2F').replace('@', '%40');
}
$('input#q').keyup(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 13) {
  if($('input#q').val().length > 2) 
  { 
   $('input#q').val() = urlencode($('input#q').val());
   document.search_form.submit();
  }
 }
});
$('input#search').click(function() {
 if($('input#q').val().length > 2) 
 { 
  $('input#q').val() = urlencode($('input#q').val());
  document.search_form.submit();
 } 
});
</script>
```

when i click the search button i get the following error : "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"
But the code is actually the same as when i press "enter". Can someone explain?

Comment: In the `urlencode()` function you should be using `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` instead of `escape()`, which was deprecated about ten years ago: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh9be5xc(VS.85).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeh9cef7(VS.85).aspx https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURI https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't assign a new value to the result of a function

```
$('input#q').val() = urlencode($('input#q').val());
```

Use this instead:

```
$('input#q').val(urlencode($('input#q').val()))
```

It wouldn't work with the keypress either - maybe the page is simply submitted after the same js error occurs.

Answer (score -5):

Why are you assinging a result of a function like this:

```
$("input#q").val = urlencode($('input#q').val())
```

Use this instead

```
$("input").val(urlencode($('input#q').val())
```

Comment: you can't copy and paste dude