# what is the cause of this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945302/uncaught-referenceerror-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment)

I cannot provide any code because I feel it will take the thread away from the root question and lead to suggestions for hacks, jquery, or workarounds. I need to learn what is implied or causes the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Thanks in advance for any information as I cannot find it in any ref pages, tutorials, or documentation.

Comment: `2 = 3;` is an invalid left hand side.

Comment: Chaos, i'm not sure why you pointed to a duplicate then closed this thread when the duplicate gives vague answers much like your own and also suggests workarounds. If you are not comfortable with the level of clarity I have requested you should have just left it for someone else instead of bullying users into your forums socially acceptable form of questioning. I see a lot of bullying around jquery on this forum and I find no difference in your closing of this thread.

Comment: @Richard: I agree, that question qualifies poorly as a duplicate. To give a general and clumsy answer, the left hand side of the assignment operator `=` is expected to be a resolved binding to an identifier. So `2 = 3;` gives a `ReferenceError` because `2` is not a valid identifier. The return value of a function is invalid, even if it is returning a String that represents a valid identifier or an Object to which properties could be assigned, because the identifier would need to have been previously resolved. If you're running your code in *strict mode*, a yet undeclared identifier...

Comment: ...like `x=123;` (instead of `var x=123;` or `var x; x=123;`) will give a `ReferenceError`. But if you're not in *strict mode*, then it allows the assignment, and creates a global variable. Hopefully this info is *mostly* correct and somewhat understandable for you. For more info, I'd [start here](http://es5.github.com/#x15.11.6.3) in this Annotated ECMAScript spec, and follow the links around a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and link. the problem is exactly inline with your explanation. style.z-index= should have been style.zIndex= . Thx again.