# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment When Clicking a Link

Tags: php, html

I have looked for every solution, but I still can't figure this out.

```
<td align="center">
    <?php if($dt->key_status === 1){ ?>
        <a href="javascript:;" title="Return Key" onClick="index.php?mod=form&act=abkrk&vid=<?=$dt->vehicle_id?>"><img src="images/icons/returnkey.png" alt="Return Key" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
    <?php }else{ ?>        
        <a href="javascript:;" title="Get Key" onClick="index.php?mod=form&act=abkgk&vid=<?=$dt->vehicle_id?>"><img src="images/icons/getkey.png" alt="Get Key" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
    <?php } ?>
 </td>
```

When I clicked the image, I keep getting this error:

```
index.php?view=tr&sm=abk:321 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945302/uncaught-referenceerror-invalid-left-hand-side-in-assignment)

Comment: I don't see any similarity with that post. My code do not assign any value to any function.

Comment: Aaaah, I see. I moved the link to `href` and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add the link in the `onClick` attribute like that.

- The `href` attribute is for the link.
- `href="javascript:;"` means "do nothing".
- Anything in the `onClick` attribute will be triggered as *javascript*.

It should work if you change:

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Return Key" onClick="index.php?mod=form&act=abkrk&vid=<?=$dt->vehicle_id?>"><img src="images/icons/returnkey.png" alt="Return Key" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
```

to

```
<a title="Return Key" href="index.php?mod=form&act=abkrk&vid=<?=$dt->vehicle_id?>"><img src="images/icons/returnkey.png" alt="Return Key" width="16" height="16" border="0" /></a>
```